# TypeError: function takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given) ,python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a trackbar for contours but when I run the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: thresh_callback() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

the code:

```
def thresh_callback(thresh,blur,img):
    edges = cv.Canny(blur,thresh,thresh*2)
    drawing = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)     # Image to draw the contours
    contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(edges,cv.RETR_TREE,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours:
        color = np.random.randint(0,255,(3)).tolist()  # Select a random color
        cv.drawContours(drawing,[cnt],0,color,2)
        cv.imshow('output',drawing)
    cv.imshow('input',img)

def Pics():
    vc = cv.VideoCapture(2)
    retVal, frame = vc.read();
    while True :
        if frame is not None:
            imgray = cv.cvtColor(frame,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            blur = cv.GaussianBlur(imgray,(5,5),0)
            thresh = 100
            max_thresh = 255
            cv.createTrackbar('canny thresh:','input',thresh,max_thresh,thresh_callback)
            thresh_callback(thresh,blur,frame)
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        if cv.waitKey() & 0xFF == 27:
            break
    cv1.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: The examples I've seen only pass in a low threshold to the callback, so just *one* argument.

Comment: I think `cv` (legacy module, as opposed to cv2...) doesn't return frames, images, etc - it behaves more like a c-function in that you pass in the outputs. This means that `blur` (and possibly `frame`) is probably empty?

Comment: @jmetz: IT is the `createTrackbar` function that is passed the callback, it in turn invokes the callback with one argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I see what you mean; is the error definitely being thrown in `createTrackbar` though, and not the subsequent call to `thresh_callback`?

Comment: @jmetz: which is why a full traceback would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `thresh_callback` into `cv.createTrackbar`, and it is somewhere in there that your function is getting called with only one argument. I assume that you still want to use the `blur` and `frame` that you determine in your code, so trying using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to set those for you:

```
import functools

...

        partialed_callback = functools.partial(thresh_callback, blur=blur, img=frame)
        cv.createTrackbar('canny thresh:','input',thresh,max_thresh,partialed_callback)
```

This creates a version of your function for which `blur` and `frame` are already set, so your `thresh_callback` function will be called with the `frame` and `blur` defined in the loop and the `thresh` provided from within `createTrackbar`.

Also, you probably don't want to be calling `thresh_callback(thresh,blur,frame)` in the line after calling `cv.createTrackbar`, as that will mean it gets called twice and always with `thresh=100` the second time.

Comment: @ Rob Watts I tried the functools.partial but I get this error: 
TypeError: thresh_callback() got an unexpected keyword argument 'frame'

Comment: @user3433195 Oops, that should have been `img=frame`, rather than `frame=frame`. I had been looking at where you called it rather than where you defined it.

Comment: That's probably because you're calling `thresh_callback` right after `createTrackbar`. Try removing that line and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @ Rob WAtts okay now i get no errors but I can't control the trackbar position it stays in one position(in this case 100)?!!

Comment: @ Rob Watts no it doesn't

Comment: It might be because you're calling `createTrackbar` within your loop. You might be creating a new trackbar at each step, always starting at 100. So it might not be that it's stuck, but that it gets recreated back at the starting point whenever you try to move it. If you aren't sure how to fix that you might want to ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your function `thresh_callback` as a callback to `cv.createTrackbar(` method.
It looks like this method expects a single-argument function to call for some event.